# C# .NET DLL Won't Build Because of System.Web conflicts

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm having an issue with my Class Library in Visual Studio C# Express 2010. The project is configured with a target framework of the .NET 4.0 (not Client Profile).

In my class library, I have added a reference to System.Web to get the URL Encoding to work for my oAuth library.

When building the DLL, and the associated testing application, I get the following error:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'TwitterAPI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\sammarks\Documents\Programming\Twitter.NET\Tester\Program.cs   5   7   Tester
```

And, I get the follow warning message:

```
Warning 2   The referenced assembly "C:\Users\sammarks\Documents\Programming\Twitter.NET\TwitterAPI\bin\Release\TwitterAPI.dll" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.   Tester
```

I'm not sure why it does this, but that's why I came here. I've tried retargeting the class library to 3.5, but that did nothing but mess it up further.

I've also tried to re-add the System.Web to the references, but that didn't help either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Target the *full* .NET Framework 4.0 for access to System.Web (**not** the Client Profile):

- [.NET Framework Client Profile assemblies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2008/05/21/net-framework-client-profile-justin-van-patten.aspx)

[image]

Comment: Nevermind, didn't realize you meant the .NET Framework 4 itself, instead of Client.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/7301dec4-4b96-444d-88bb-630125d080e4

Comment: Aha! My tester program was targeting the Client Profile. All working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Might sound silly, but have you tried restarting Visual Studio ?

It sometimes tends to miss a reference or two.

Comment: Nope. I restarted it, and it didn't work. I was going to be so shocked if that actually worked, though lol.

Comment: Does this answer have something to do with your user name?

Comment: It happened to me that I had a public class with public members and I couldn't acces them because it said it was protected or private.

A restart fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your class library has a reference to the client profile, while your test executable is referencing the non-client profile. I am gleaning this from the warning:

```
...currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client ...
```

Comment: So does this mean that I need to change the targeted framework to .NET 4.0 Client Profile?

Comment: No, it should not be the client profile; check that both assemblies target the same version, because that warning looks suspiciously like one of them is targeting the client profile. Also, make sure you save after changing the properties (just doing a build or debug does not save changes to the assembly properties IIRC).